# Excel Pivot Table with Microsoft Access Connection

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-access, database

I have a pivot table which sources its data from a query within an Access database file. Whenever I make an update, I make a copy of both the Excel and Access files first - and carry out the update on these new copies. This requires me to update the connection within the workbook, as the new workbook will still be linked to the old Access file.

Would there be any problems if I just update the 'Connection string' without updating the 'Connection file' in 'Connection Properties'?

The connection file is:

> oldpath\oldfile.accdb

Whereas the connection string would be:

> Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;User ID=Admin;Data
>   Source=**newpath\newfile.accdb**;Mode=Share Deny Write;Extended
>   Properties="";Jet OLEDB:System database="";Jet OLEDB:Registry
>   Path="";Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=6;Jet OLEDB:Database Locking Mode=0;Jet
>   OLEDB:Global Partial Bulk Ops=2;Jet OLEDB:Global Bulk
>   Transactions=1;Jet OLEDB:New Database Password="";Jet OLEDB:Create
>   System Database=False;Jet OLEDB:Encrypt Database=False;Jet OLEDB:Don't
>   Copy Locale on Compact=False;Jet OLEDB:Compact Without Replica
>   Repair=False;Jet OLEDB:SFP=False;Jet OLEDB:Support Complex
>   Data=False;Jet OLEDB:Bypass UserInfo Validation=False

I just tried it and the pivot table seems to update fine - but I am not sure if there may be anything I am missing out on?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will connect to whatever is in the connection string, so changing the the Source there will accomplish the goal of having it use the new Access file. The downside, is that the connection file doesn't change to match the new source and will still show the old Access file which may cause confusion later.